# php echo multiple backgrounds at same time

Tags: php, css

I am not finding anything, or not searching the right terms here on SO. I want to have two backgrounds, one underlay and one overlay each `echo` by php. Something like this -

```
.split-left{background-image:url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($pid, 'full')", url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(2789), 'large' );?>"); overflow: hidden; border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;}
```

I have also tried:

```
.split-left{background-image:url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($pid, 'full'), url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'large' );?>"); overflow: hidden; border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;}
```

with no success. What is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right lines, but you're forgetting to break out of PHP between the two URLs.

Try this version. I've added some newlines so you can see more clearly where the URLs are, and where PHP starts and stops.

```
.split-left{
    background-image:
    url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($pid, 'full'); ?>"),
    url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'large'); ?>");
    overflow: hidden; border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;}
```